# Reset checkboxes to false

Tags: checkbox, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google spreadsheet where column A has checkboxes in each row. I have written a script to perform a function on all rows where the checkboxes are checked, but I want to add in at the end a reset function so that all checked boxes are unchecked again after the script is run.

I've tried using a for loop like this:

```
var dataRange = sheet.getRange('A3:A');
var values = dataRange.getValues();

for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {     
    if (values[i][j] == true) {
      values[i].setValue(false);
    }
  }    
}
```

But clearly this doesn't work as I get an error.

Does anyone know how this could be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this modification? I think that there are several solutions for your situation. So please think of this as one of them.

#### Modification points :

- The reason of the issue is `values[i].setValue(false);`. `values[i]` is an array. Please use the range for `setValue()`.

  - But to use `setValue()` in the for loop leads to higher cost. So in this modification, I used `setValues()`.
- Put "false" to `values`, if `values[i][j]` is "true".
- Put the modified values to the sheet using `setValues()`.

#### Modified script :

```
var dataRange = sheet.getRange('A3:A');
var values = dataRange.getValues();
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
    if (values[i][j] == true) {
      values[i][j] = false; // Modified
    }
  }
}
dataRange.setValues(values); // Added
```

#### Reference :

- [setValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValue(Object))
- [setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

If this was not what you want, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

Comment: @DaveB1 I'm glad your issue was solved. Thank you, too.

Comment: As an additional information, if you want to check the value of ``1`` and empty value in the cells, these threads might be useful. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54742828/7108653 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/54795712/7108653

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, thanks for this solution, and I'm glad that OP has got this issue solved. I've encountered the same issue trying to reset all checkboxes in my sheet to false, and have implemented your code but not had any success. If you have any free time, [would you mind having a look at my code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60929703/reset-checkboxes-to-false-implemented-solution-not-working) and letting me know if there's an obvious fix? Cheers :)

Answer (score 5):

#### Update:

You can  now use `range.uncheck()` directly on the range

---

Alternatively, Since you want to uncheck everything in the range (and all of the range have checkboxes in them), just do:

```
sheet.getRange('A3:A').setValue(false);
```

without checking/looping.

Answer (score 3):

The remove-check-marks method is "uncheck"…

```js
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('A21:A59');
  range.uncheck();
```

Answer (score 2):

By highlighting all the cells in the range that you want to "uncheck" hold Crtl and double tap the spacebar.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'm not sure your answer is exactly what Dave was looking for. The user asked for a script to reset all checkbkoxes, not how to it manually.

Comment: Not the answer the OP wanted but it is a simple solution to the problem I was trying to solve!

Answer (score 1):

This solution posted above does reset all checkboxes;
however, it also unexpectedly changes cells with the value of **1** in it to ***FALSE.***

I want to make a script to reset checkboxes on ALL sheets...

```
function resetCheckBoxesAllSheets() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var allsheets = ss.getSheets();
for (var s in allsheets){
var sheet=allsheets[s]

var dataRange = sheet.getRange('A4:Z100');
var values = dataRange.getValues();
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
    if (values[i][j] == true) {
      values[i][j] = false; // Modified
    }
  }
}
dataRange.setValues(values);


}//end of  sheets loop.
}// end of function...
```

Comment: This also replaces all formulas within a range.  Any thoughts on how to get it to only replace checkboxes with a script aht doesn't need google API

Comment: There's is new method: `range.unCheck()`. It should help.

Answer (score 0):

I have set one checkbox instead of caption as shown in the picture
[image: Sheet Image]

I write a script for check the data range and check uncheck all accordingly.
Here is the script.

```
    function onEdit(e){
  Logger.log('OnEdit'); 
  var range = e.range;
  var cl  = range.getColumn(); 
  var rw = range.getRow(); 
  Logger.log('Row = ' + rw + '   Column = ' + cl); 
  var ActiveSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();  
  if(ActiveSheet.getName() === 'Companies' && rw == 1 && cl == 5){
    var isAllTrue  = ActiveSheet.getRange(rw, cl).getValue(); 
    if(isAllTrue == true){
      var Avals = ActiveSheet.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
      var Alast = Avals.filter(String).length;
      ActiveSheet.getRange(2, 5, Number(Alast-1)).setValue(true); 
    }
    else
    {
      var Avals = ActiveSheet.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
      var Alast = Avals.filter(String).length;
      ActiveSheet.getRange(2, 5, Number(Alast-1)).setValue(false); 
    }
  }  
}

Change sheet name as per your need.
```

Note: create onedit trigger for same function if not trigger auto.