# Reset Checkboxes and Delete Notes on Defined sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

I need to reset checkboxes to FALSE (Unchecked) and also delete all notes from defined sheets.

Also need a script that deletes all notes from a Google sheet (all sheets)

I tried combining numerous different scripts.

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/115076/how-to-run-script-on-multiple-google-sheet-tabs

[Re-set checkboxes to false - Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51185819/re-set-checkboxes-to-false-google-apps-script/54740966#54740966) -- The problem with this script is that is turns cells with a value of 1 into cells that say "FALSE"

```
function ResetCheckBoxesAndClearNotesOnDefinedSheets(){
    var tabs = [
        'Checkboxes 1',
        'Checkboxes 2',
        'Checkboxes 3',
        'Another Checkbox tab',
        'Yet another checkbox tab'
    ];


  //LOOP THROUGH TABS LISTED ABOVE
    var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
        var sheet=ss.getSheetByName(tabs[i]);

  //CLEAR NOTES ON TABS LISTED ABOVE    
      sheet.clearNotes();

 // CLEAR CHECKBOXES ON TABS LISTED ABOVE

var dataRange = sheet.getRange('A:I');
var values = dataRange.getValues();
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
    if (values[i][j] == true) {
      values[i][j] = false; // Modified
    }
  }
}
dataRange.setValues(values);


}//end of  sheets loop.
  }
```

ACTUAL RESULTS:
-It does not loop through the pages and delete the notes.  It also does not loop through and change all checkboxes in the tabs to unchecked.. and it sometimes replaces a "1" with a FALSE

EXPECTED RESULTS:
-Reset all checkboxes on defined sheets
-Clear all notes on Defined sheets (or entire Spreadsheet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- In your script, the variable of `i` is used at both `for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {` and `for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {`.

  - By this, the value of `i` of `for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {` is not increased every 1.
  - I think that this is one of your issues of `It does not loop through the pages and delete the notes.`.
  - For example, please modify to `for (var k = 0; k < tabs.length; k++) {var sheet=ss.getSheetByName(tabs[k]);`.
- Equality comparison `==` is used for comparing the boolean.

  - I think that this is another issue of `it sometimes replaces a "1" with a FALSE`.
  - Please modify this to the strict equality comparison `===`.

#### Modified script:

Please modify as follows.

From:

```
for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(tabs[i]);
```

To:

```
for (var k = 0; k < tabs.length; k++) {
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(tabs[k]);
```

And

From:

```
if (values[i][j] == true) {
```

To:

```
if (values[i][j] === true) {
```

#### Reference:

- [Equality comparisons and sameness](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness)

If I misunderstood your question, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

Comment: Well, now I can't figure out why this script is Deleting the hyperlinks URLs in cells.  It will not delete the text or the formatting that makes them look like hyperlinks.  The URL is deleted though.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @B D I'm sorry. I cannot understand your current situation. In order to correctly replicate and understand your situation, can you post it as new question? At that time, please include the detail information of your current situation. By this, users including me can think of about your issue. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Comment: Thank you - I posted at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54929107/google-script-to-clear-checkboxes-and-notes-in-cells-unexpectedly-clears-hyperli

Comment: @B D Thank you for replying. I saw your new question. I'm glad the new issue was resolved.

Comment: @B D I apologize I misunderstood your situation. There are several useful comments in your new question. So their comments will be able to resolve your issue. If you need some helps, please tell me.

Comment: Thanks -- I tried Spreadsheet Service script at the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54935257/finding-all-checkboxes-in-a-google-sheet. I get error about Sheets not being defined. There is a comment that says // Enable before use... but I'm not sure what that is referring to...

I've tried to make values into formulas.  Then it deletes everything EXCEPT the formulas...

Even if I can find the checkboxes, I don't know how to make the script just update the checkboxes to false or unchecked.

Comment: @B D At your new question, it seems that the discussions are progressed. I think that your issue will be resolved by the discussions.

Comment: I can't figure out what they mean by "Enable before use" and then once I get the checkboxes "returned" I'm still not clear on how to manipulate them.  I read through and not sure where to add  spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate and how to batchupdate to FALSE

Comment: @B D I cannot understand about ``Enable before use``. Where can I see it? I apologize that I cannot understand your current situation.