# Re-set checkboxes to true (dealing with blanks)- Google Apps Script

Tags: checkbox, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I found the snippet below here: [Re-set checkboxes to false - Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51185819/re-set-checkboxes-to-false-google-apps-script)

I'm interested in editing this to set false checkboxes to true, specifically adding to it to skip blank cells. Can't find anything helpful on skipping blanks.

```html
function resetCheckBoxesAllSheets() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var allsheets = ss.getSheets();
for (var s in allsheets){
var sheet=allsheets[s]

var dataRange = sheet.getRange('A4:Z100');
var values = dataRange.getValues();
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
    if (values[i][j] == true) {
      values[i][j] = false;
    }
  }
}
dataRange.setValues(values);


}
}
```

Comment: Although i'm not sure about your actual situation, for example, how about modifying from ``if (values[i][j] == true) {values[i][j] = false;}`` to ``if (values[i][j] === false) {values[i][j] = true;}``? I think that [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54742828/7108653) might be useful.

Comment: Clever. That's done it.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to flip flop the values of a set of checkboxes this will do it for a given column active range:

Note: capitalization counts and yes those are strings.  If you have any doubts about it then use your script editor's debugger to see what is in your checkboxes.  That's how I figured it out when I started playing with them.

```
function resetCheckBoxesAllSheets() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet=ss.getActiveSheet()
  var dataRange = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var values = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i=0;i<values.length;i++) {
    values[i][0]=values[i][0]?"FALSE":"TRUE";
  }
  dataRange.setValues(values);
}
```

So in your particular case, assuming everything else in your function works then try this:

```
function resetCheckBoxesAllSheets() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var allsheets = ss.getSheets();
  for (var s in allsheets){
    var sheet=allsheets[s]
    var dataRange = sheet.getRange('A4:Z100');
    var values = dataRange.getValues();
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
        if (values[i][j]) {
          values[i][j] = "FALSE";
        }
      }
    }
    dataRange.setValues(values); 
  }
}
```