# Ticking checkbox triggers function to add time stamp

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm building a spreadsheet that tracks specific data.  I want to place a timestamp in the corresponding adjacent cell when I tick a checkbox - alternative I would be happy with a note on the checkbox stating the time it was last ticked TRUE.

I have literally spent an entire day searching **everything** on Stackoverflow and google, and I have tried many different methods and functions.  Primarily I have been using the `onEdit(e)` function to (try and) add the time stamp.  Early attempts identified a known flaw that meant `onEdit(e)` wasn't capturing all instances of the checkbox change state.  I changed my approach accordingly, both attempting to add the timestamp to the corresponding adjacent cell, and also add a note to the checkbox cell - both seemed to work sporadically which was extremely frustrating.

I have three primary issues with this problem at the moment:

1. Knowing the syntax for checking the value of the checkbox (do I use ==, or ===, and do I use `'`', `"`, or no quotation marks?).  That sounds like a very stupid question, but I have learning difficulties and have significant trouble retaining written information in my memory  :(
2. Successfully setting an `if' -> 'else if' statement that will "toggle" the timestamp on or off depending on the state of the checkbox.
3. I would prefer to set a note with the timestamp on the checkbox cell that is cleared when the checkbox is unticked - however the few times I did get it to work the timezone was incorrect.  I did a lot of reading about `timezone` but without a working example I was unable to comprehend how to implement it into my code.  I'm +10 GMT

I have provided a cut down version of my spreadsheet containing only the specific sheet & code I am having trouble with:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NCdMziBpj0joSv9lQfqT9etz9hMsvgMeuT8X9XTxR20/edit?usp=sharing

Here is the latest iteration of code I have been working on.  I've probably attempted half a dozen completely different functions but have deleted each one after several hours of hitting brick walls:

```
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  if(ss.getName() == "Quests" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
    var tickboxCell = s.getActiveCell();
    if(tickboxCell.getColumn() == 3 && tickboxCell.getValue() === 'TRUE' ) { //checks the status of the tickbox
      var dateCell = tickboxCell.offset(0, 1);
      dateCell.setValue(new Date());
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the sample code I modified for adding a note to the checkbox:

```
function setNote(note){
    var note = note;
    var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell();

    if(note == ""){
        cell.clearNote();
    }else{
        cell.setNote(note);
    }
}
```

I would expect that any time a checkbox is ticked, either the corresponding cell to the right would input `date()`, or alternatively the checkbox would add a note stating "Quest Completed: dd/mm/yyy" (+10 GMT timezone).  I would then expect the timestamp cell to clear, or the note to be cleared if the checkbox state is unticked.

Comment: Checkboxes can have any value signify "checked" state, and any other value signify "unchecked". You can create checkboxes where "FALSE" means "checked" and "TRUE" means "unchecked". You need to compare the cell value to the data validation rule's criteria, see my [q & a here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54935257/finding-all-checkboxes-in-a-google-sheet/). As far as `==` vs `===`, prefer strict equality in almost every case you can conceive of.

Comment: Well you tell me how to format code in the comments so it's not a jumbled mess.  When I'm happy with a final answer I'll post it accordingly.  What else do you want to tell me I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If Cooper's post answered your single, specific question, then mark it as the answer. (One question = one post.) If you have a second or a follow-up question, ask a new one, and give it the same workup you did here, where you explain the issue and what you've done to try to solve it, and what related SO / internet posts you found when researching it. Comments aren't for posting complicated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Cooper who put me on the right path with his code.  It didn't do exactly what I was looking for, but it enabled me to make a few minor changes to it to get exactly what I was looking for.

EDIT:  I have found the solution for `setNote` as well which I will provide here.

Code for adding/removing date to adjacent cell:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getSheet().getName() != 'Quests') { return; }
  if (e.range.columnStart==3 && e.value=="TRUE") {
    e.range.offset(0,1).setValue(new Date());
  }
  else if (e.range.columnStart==3 && e.value=="FALSE") {
    e.range.offset(0,1).clearContent();
  }
}
```

Code for adding/removing `setNote` from tickbox with correct timezone:

```
  if(e.range.getSheet().getName() != 'Quests') { return; }
  if(e.range.columnStart==3 && e.value=="TRUE") {
    e.range.setNote('Completed: ' + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss"));
  }
  else if (e.range.columnStart==3 && e.value=="FALSE") {
    e.range.clearNote();
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if(e.range.getSheet().getName() != 'Quests') { return; }
  if(e.range.columnStart==3 && e.value=="TRUE") {
    e.range.offset(0,1).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyyyMMdd:HHmm"));
  }
}
```

Comment: Advise me please Cooper - should I accept your answer as without it I wouldn't have gotten to my final solution?  Or should I accept mine as it's the final script that does everything I was asking in the question.  I'm greatly appreciative of your help.

Comment: The goal of this site is programmers helping each other become better better programmers not who has the most points. Personally, I take great pride in being able to modify my own programs to my own needs and I’m glad that you were able to take the initiative to improve upon my work and get an answer that you desired so choose your own answer and be happy about it.

Comment: Thank you Cooper, you're very kind.  Can I come straight to you and avoid all this judgey cliche crowd in future? j/k :D

Comment: The best way to utilize stack overflow in my opinion is to create a minimal complete verifiable example that contains the essence of what your question is. That’s what I do in my own work. When I start to run into a problem that looks like something that I’ve never seen before I start to try to think about how I can write this minimal complete verifiable example so that I can submit it as a question to stack overflow. Very often it helps me to solve my own problem. When it doesn’t it becomes a question.

Comment: Trying to avoid other volunteers will only hurt you because many of them know a lot more than I do.

Comment: That's exactly what I did.  I stripped down my entire spreadsheet to just the problem that I had, even ripping out most of the content from the sheet that I was having trouble with.  Still got downvoted.  At least it's back to 0 now!