# Using a script to generate docs from rows in Google Sheet if checkbox is checked

Tags: checkbox, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to generate Google Docs / PDFs from rows in a Google Sheet. My aim is for the user presses a UI menu button, and it will only generate the Docs if a checkbox is ticked for that row.

I've got the rest of the code working, its just finding the why to get the script to check if a checkbox is ticket and only generate the doc if it is checked.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code (which you should post), I can say that you need to add an IF statement in the beggining, that will check if a certain cell is true or false (which is the state of checked and unchecked).

Perhaps something like this might work:

```
if(sheet.getRange(your range/cell/var here).getValue() == 'TRUE' {
    your code here
  }
```

Comment: A checkbox can have any value signify the "checked" state and any other value signify the "unchecked" state. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54935257/finding-all-checkboxes-in-a-google-sheet/54935258#54935258