# Reset checkboxes to false - implemented solution not working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a column of checkboxes which the user can set to true or false - I want to run a Google Apps Script on the click of a button which resets the value of all the checkboxes to False.

I found a related question, and attempted to implement [the solution from the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51186036/1907765). Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work as intended, and I don't know enough about Apps Script to understand why. Here is my code (barely modified from Tanaike's solution):

```
function resetBoard() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange('L5:L');
  var values = dataRange.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
      if (values[i][j] == true) {
        values[i][j] == false;
      }
    }
  }

  dataRange.setValues(values);
}
```

Here is the sheet - the checkboxes in Column L are the ones I'm trying to reset. After I press the button to execute the script, it says that the script is finished, but nothing has changed:

[image]

Is there a simple mistake that explains why this isn't working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my understanding:

- You want to change the checkboxes of the cells "L5:L" to `false`.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

#### Modification points:

- In your script, `values[i][j] == false;` is required to be modified. In this case, `values[i][j]` is compared with `false`. So when you use this script, please modify to `values[i][j] = false;`.
- In this case, when `resetBoard()` is run, how about unchecking all checkboxes of "L5:L"?

#### Modified script:

```
function resetBoard() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('L5:L').uncheck();
}
```

#### Reference:

- [uncheck()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#uncheck)

Comment: Oh brilliant, it works perfectly! I didn't know that there was a much simpler solution, thank you :). Do you have any idea why the first solution might not have worked?

Comment: @Lou Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About the issue of your script, I forgot to add the modification point. So I added it. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: Oh I see, thank you! So `==` is used for comparison, and `=` for assignment, I'm assuming. Well thanks again for all your help :)